# cannot send headers after they are set

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I have this code in my log in page

```
//get login
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    const flashMessages = 
res.locals.getMessages( );
    if( flashMessages.error ){
        res.render( 'login', {
            showErrors: true,
            errors: flashMessages.error
        });
    }else{
        res.render( 'login' )
    }
    //console.log( 'flash', flashMessages);
  res.render('login', { title: 'LOG IN'});
});
```

And at times, when i try to get the log in page, i end up seeing a blank page or at times, when i try to log in, i and stucked in the log in page instead of the dashboard. Sometimes, i don't see the value in the title. And when i check my logs (nodemon) i see this error

```
Error: /var/www/html/akahline/views/error.hbs: Can't set headers after they are sent.               at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
```

Comment: this is not needed `res.render('login', { title: 'LOG IN'});` or replace it with         res.render( 'login' )

Answer (score 0):

You are sending out your rendering twice. The best method is return after the `flashMessages.error` like so

```
//get login
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    const flashMessages = res.locals.getMessages( );
    if( flashMessages.error ){
        return res.render( 'login', {
            showErrors: true,
            errors: flashMessages.error
        })
    }

  //console.log( 'flash', flashMessages);
  res.render('login', { title: 'LOG IN'});
});
```

This will return if there is an error the login with `showErrors` and if not return the login with your `title`

Comment: Thanks i appeciate